# Access Freemind 1.0 from the laucher

Tags: kubuntu, launcher

There is a problem with Freemind 0.9, which is the version I get if I use `sudo apt-get install freemind`.

When trying to share a `.mm` file between Windows Freemind and Ubuntu Freemind, I get the error

> Error while parsing file:freemind.main.XMLParseException: XML Parse
>   Exception during parsing of a map element at line 1: Expected: =

Googling, I find advice at [PLABO: fixing "Error while parsing file:freemind.main.XMLParseException: XML Parse Exception during parsing of a map element at line 1: Expected: ="](http://pablomarin-garcia.blogspot.com/2013/06/fixing-error-while-parsing.html) to instead use Freemind 1.0.

I don't do a lot of manual installs in Linux.

I first download, then unzip, and put the directory in `/opt/`. I then add to `~/.profile` the line `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/freemind-bin-max-1.0.0_RC_4/`.

But this seems to only work for calling `freemind.sh` from the terminal. I'd like to call from the launcher.

Is there a better way to do all this? Is there a relatively easy way that is also better?

I've checked the [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Download) site, they only provide 0.9 for Debian.

**Note**: I am Kubuntu user.

Comment: @Braiam, I am in kubuntu, but I will take a look.

Comment: Through it says "unity" all DE actually support that.

Comment: @Braiam, I right clicked the Launcher button (KDE gear), clicked `edit applications...`, and it was pretty smooth sailing from there; even added a downloaded logo. Thanks! I'm so reliant on `apt`, but relieved the final step was easy. Thanks for realizing what I had left to do, I could not see it tonight.